# How to set multiple data directories when storing data in 3 copies of cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

May I ask if I use 3 copies to store data in the cluster version of Apache IoTDB, is it still possible for me to configure multiple data directories? If I can still set multiple data directories, then how should I set them in cluster version of IoTDB?